# How to convert circled numbers to numbers ? (① to 1)

Tags: text, encoding, ocr, utf, cjk

I would like to convert numbers from a string I receive after an OCR recognition over Japanese text.

For example, when I extract a date:

```
③① 年 ⑫ 月 ①③ 日
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
31 年 12 月 13 日
```

What would be the best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [unicodedata](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/unicodedata.html)

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.normalize("NFKC","③① 年 ⑫ 月 ①③ 日"))
```

The result is this,

```
31 年 12 月 13 日
```

This also converts other variation of Japanese digits, full-width digits.

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.normalize("NFKC","123①②③１２３"))
```

to

```
123123123
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worked perfectly. For reference, here is the equivalent in golang: `norm.NFKC.Bytes([]byte("③① 年 ⑫ 月 ①③ 日"))` (import "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"). https://blog.golang.org/normalization

Comment: In Javascript, it would be: `"③① 年 ⑫ 月 ①③ 日".normalize ('NFKC')` using [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

Comment: Thank you. In PHP, you need php_intl extension and the code would be `<?php echo Normalizer::normalize('③① 年 ⑫ 月 ①③ 日', Normalizer::NFKC);`

Comment: In Java, it would be: `Normalizer.normalize("③① 年 ⑫ 月 ①③ 日", Normalizer.Form.NFKC)` see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have the text OCR'd to the circled numbers in your question, a simple text replace will suffice. Here's how you'd do it in Python:

```py
def uncircle(s):
    for i in range(1, 21):
        s = s.replace(chr(0x245f + i), str(i))
    return s.replace('\u24ea', '0')
```

The circled numbers 1 through 20 are the Unicode codepoints 0x2460 through 0x2473, and the circled number 0 is the Unicode codepoint 0x24ea.